# Angular JS - Simple Text Change does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am introducing myself to AngularJS and I am finding a few difficulties.

I am trying to build a simple controller to just change text, later it will call a rest API but I am failing to do so.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="assets/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/index.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/SliderController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="leftside">
            <div class="slideshow" ng-app="sliderApp" ng-controller="SliderController">
                <slider images="images" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            <div ng-app="Authentication" ng-controller="LoginController">
                <form style="padding-top: 150px" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
                    <p><input type="text" class="text-line" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" /></p>
                    <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text-line" placeholder="password"></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">LOGIN</button>
                </form>
                You spanned: <span ng-bind-html="myTxt"></span>
                <div>You Wrote: {{myTxt}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var authenticationApp = angular.module('Authentication', []);

authenticationApp.controller("LoginController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
    }
});
```

For some reason after `You Spanned:` nothing shows up and after `You Wrote:` it appears `{{myTxt}}`. I am using AngularJS 1.5.9

[Example of what is appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTIZz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ng-apps in html. In this case only the first will work. You can always test if your app is working by putting into html something obvious like {{1+1}}. You can also bootstrap your app manually by angular.bootstrap.

Comment: it was wrong indeed, unfortunately didn't fix it :(

Comment: You cannot have two ng-apps declared in html. Only the first one will work. If you want to have more than one, the second should be bootstrapped using angular.bootstrap. Anybody correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: that is exacly right! if you want to update your answer go ahead and I will accept :)